# how to use downloaded firmware from firmware Finder

Tags: updates, huawei, device-firmware

I have jsnL21 C432 4/64 version

I upgraded my phone by 3 button method from 8.2 to 9.0.1.158. Using Firmware Finder, I found a newer version of my firmware in 9.0.1.162 which has a lot of improvement and battery optimization. I want to flash it on my device. I downloaded the firmware but it has 2 files:

1. Update.zip 2.24GB
2. Update_full_jsn_l21_hw_eu.zip 643MB

I know I should extract update.app into dload folder but the problem is I have 2 zips and inside of each files has a separated Update.app. How to upgrade with these files?

[Firmware Finder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teammt.gmanrainy.huaweifirmwarefinder)

Comment: You you are talking about third party apps and software like "firmware finder" you should provide a link to the software. Please edit your question and update it with this information.

Comment: yeah sure i did that

Comment: Have you read and act on the "Important notice" in the app description?: `Before do anything with your phone i request you, read XDA or 4PDA threads about your phone and how install firmwares or go to telegram chat and give your question.`

Comment: yeah i read that but its nothing there :| about 2 files its just a instruction to do it with 1 file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use both files to update your device.
First use `Update.zip` which is the full firmware image, then `Update_full_jsn_l21_hw_eu.zip` which is the data file.